# Can a polynomial have repeated complex roots?

Tags: linear-algebra

Can a polynomial have repeated complex roots - or is it only possible that it can have repeated real roots?

If so, can you please also provide an example of a polynomial with complex roots where you calculate the roots and end up with the result? Your time is much appreciated :))

Comment: $(x - i)^2$ has the root $i$ repeated twice.

Comment: @Leo Post your comment as an answer. You can even provide one with real coefficients.

Comment: I think you mean "a polynomial with real coefficients".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about the following:

$(x^2 + r^2)^2 = 0$

This equation has double roots at $x = \pm ir$

Specific example:

If $r=1$, the above equation becomes

$(x^2 + 1)^2 = 0$

or, $x^4 + 2x^2 + 1 = 0$

Answer (score 0):

Other examples can be: $x^2+1=0$ so $x=\pm i$ or more generally $x^2+k^2=0$ with solutions $x=\pm ki$.